# Two-element vs two-elements

Tags: grammatical-number

Why "[two-element Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra)" not "two-elements Boolean algebra"? The number of elements (two) is plural, but the word "element" is singular. This looks like a discrepancy for me.

Comment: It is an adjective. Adjectives in English have no plural forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is correct English. Other examples:

- two-time loser
- three-piece suit
- four-wheel drive
- [Five Man Electrical Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Man_Electrical_Band)
- six-string guitar
- [Seven Nation Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Nation_Army)

When a number and a noun are joined together as a hyphenated adjective, the noun is in the singular and not plural.

**But** if its an adjective and a noun, the noun *can* be plural if the context requires it:

- the [many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of quantum mechanics
- [broken-windows policing](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/09/07/fixing-broken-windows)

It might not make sense, but that's the way it is.

PS, the hyphen itself may be optional, especially with the adjective+noun versions. I think it is less often omitted with the number+noun versions.

Comment: It's fairly widespread in languages that when a noun is incorporated into a complex phrase, it loses any inflections.